# Parsing double value for current culture

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

ASP.NET MVC  doesn't bind "1.5" double value(because invalid format for current culture). So i am trying to parse it manualy for current culture.

My solution is replacing "1.5" float point with valid float seperator  for current culture.

How can i replace float seperator by valid seperator in current culture ?

Do you have better solution for it ?

Comment: Why don't you change the current culture to en-US?

Comment: Because application is Multilingual.

Comment: then why your users are not respecting their current culture and using `.` as decimal separator instead of their own culture decimal separator?

Comment: @Darin Because its an ASP.Net application and so the culture being used is the one on the server, not the one on the client.

Comment: @Justin, suffice to change the `culture` and `uiCulture` attributes of the `<globalization>` element in web.config to `auto` to modify this behavior and use the client culture.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Users doesn't need to do for respect their culture. On client side a plugin provide me float number which has no any relation on server side

Answer (score 0):

Just specify which culture you want to use when parsing:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[0]);
return double.Parse("1.5", culture.NumberFormat);
```

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: I remember i tested this and worked wrongly .. i will check again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have "1.5" parse no matter the culture, try this:

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Double.Parse("1.5", culture.NumberFormat);
```

That creates an instance of the en-US culture and tells the parser to use it in this specific case.

Comment: Rather than use an arbitrary culture like `en-US` it might be better to use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when parsing numbers.